# Python Filtering Out Events that are Outside of Date Range (Past Hour)

Tags: python, date, filter, range

I am attempting to get the scheduled "potential_individual_meetings" only if they occurred within the last hour and then send a push notification to the users who were involved in the meeting.

The push notifications send fine, but it seems they do not send all the time. It seems to me that the notification only sends when the NOW time is exactly 1 hour after the meeting was scheduled.

I tried doing the following but it seems I cannot use < and > for the Filter(). 
    NOW > ONE_HOUR & NOW < FIVE_MINUTES_AGO

Which would replace         datetime__gte=INDIVIDUAL_RANGE_START,
        datetime__lt=INDIVIDUAL_RANGE_END

I am maintaining someone else's code for a non-profit, but Python is not a strong language for me. Any help someone could give me here is greatly appreciated.

```
NOW = timezone.now()
FIVE_MINUTES_AGO = NOW - timedelta(minutes=5)
ONE_HOUR = timedelta(hours=1)
NINETY_MINUTES = timedelta(minutes=90)

INDIVIDUAL_RANGE_START = FIVE_MINUTES_AGO - ONE_HOUR
INDIVIDUAL_RANGE_END = NOW - ONE_HOUR

    potential_individual_meetings = Event.objects.filter(
        status=1,
        datetime__gte=INDIVIDUAL_RANGE_START,
        datetime__lt=INDIVIDUAL_RANGE_END
    )
    individual_meetings = [e for e in potential_individual_meetings if not e.meeting.group]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would seem to give you a range of 1 hour 5 minutes ago to 1 hour ago:

```
INDIVIDUAL_RANGE_START = FIVE_MINUTES_AGO - ONE_HOUR
INDIVIDUAL_RANGE_END = NOW - ONE_HOUR
```

What you want is probably close to:

```
INDIVIDUAL_RANGE_START = NOW - ONE_HOUR
INDIVIDUAL_RANGE_END = FIVE_MINUTES_AGO
```

Or possibly just `INDIVIDUAL_RANGE_END = NOW` but I presume you have that Five minute buffer there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

The length of your time range is only five minutes long, but it sounds like you want it to be one hour, or maybe 65 minutes.

Why not simply change this:

```
INDIVIDUAL_RANGE_END = NOW - ONE_HOUR
```

To this:

```
INDIVIDUAL_RANGE_END = NOW
```

In any event, printing the RANGE_START and RANGE_END variables, along with NOW, will probably show you what’s going wrong.